# How to determine what has gone wrong with apache

Tags: apache

Hi all I have changed some apache configuration files and when I run rcapache2 restart it displays the error
Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.

I then run the command `systemctl status httpd.service`
and it displays the error

> httpd.service
>             Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
>             Active: inactive (dead)

How do I find out which file or directory it can't find. I've looked at the error log but it doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solutions. Running rcapache2 start -t which shows exactly what has gone wrong within the configuration file.

Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-e debug` option might work. It's been a while since I used rcapache2 but it seems extra options go to the server.

[Apache options.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/httpd.html)